# References in TeX

Tags: bibliographies

I am currently using this kind of bibliography in LaTeX:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1 cm}


\bibitem{Hochstadt}M.C. Weber, Sleeping Dogs, Journal of Medical Australia (1963) 930 - 932.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Now this kind of reference shows up with a number in front. I would rather like to use a abbreviation for the paper I am talking about: So for example Weber63 or something like that. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Have a look on the bibliography styles, e.g. here [http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management] or here [http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html]

Comment: By the way, `1 cm` as the argument to `thebibliography` doesn't mean `1cm` (as in the length).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the label for each `\bibitem`:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1 cm}
  \bibitem[Weber63]{Hochstadt} ...
\end{thebibliography}
```

If you don’t specify the label for some entries, they will be numbered the normal way in their order of appearance:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{...}          % Render:
  \bibitem[a]{label1} First entry     % [a] First entry
  \bibitem{label2} Second entry       % [1] Second entry
  \bibitem[b]{label3} Third entry     % [b] Third entry
  \bibitem{label4} Fourth entry       % [2] Fourth entry
\end{thebibliography}
```